# Reuse a parent CDK Stack in other App project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

First at all, it's important mention that I'm not using CDK as usual. Instead I'm creating resources on-the-fly programatically. So, basically, I have a multi-tenant application that on onboard it's created a customer root stack, that will be included nested stacks with resources during the customer lifetime.

At the first time, a code like this was executed:

```typescript
import {App, Stack, Construct, NestedStack} from '@aws-cdk/core';

const main = async() => {
    const app = new App();

    const rootStack = new (class RootStack extends Stack {
        constructor() {
            super(app, `Customer-123-RootStack`, {});
        }
       
    });

    const tenantIamStack = new (class CustomerIamNestedClass  extends NestedStack {
        constructor() {
            super(rootStack, `BasicIAM`, {});

            const cognitoFederatedPrincipal = new iam.FederatedPrincipal('cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
                'StringEquals': {
                    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': process.env.SHARED_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
                },
                'ForAnyValue:StringLike': {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }, 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity');

            new iam.Role(this, 'IamRoleTenantUser', {
                roleName: `Customer-123-TenantUser`,
                assumedBy: cognitoFederatedPrincipal,
            });
        }
    });
}

main().then(() => console.log('done'));
```

I want now to reuse the root Stack `Customer-123-RootStack` on other Stacks created in other routines. For example, a customer will create an other AWS resource in our platform, like a AWS EventBridge rule or a ACM certificate.

If execute the same code with another nested stack, the first nested stack will be deleted.

```typescript
import {App, Stack, Construct, NestedStack} from '@aws-cdk/core';

const main = async() => {
    const app = new App();

    const rootStack = new (class RootStack extends Stack {
        constructor() {
            super(app, `Customer-123-RootStack`, {});
        }
       
    });

    const tenantAcmStack = new (class CustomerAcmNestedClass  extends NestedStack {
        constructor() {
            super(rootStack, `BasicACM`, {});

            //create ACM certificate
        }
    });
}

main().then(() => console.log('done'));
```

I have read this documentation but can't figure out how do that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing

I'm able to use SDK to get the stack but not understand how make it work with CDK.

**Edit**: to make my question more clear: I need to referente a parent existing stack (created by other app, in other moment, in other code base) to a new NestedStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and created this example repository:

- https://github.com/renanwilliam/cdk-reuse-stack-example

I have made a mix with AWS SDK CloudFormation module:

**src/index.js**:

```typescript
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as cfninc from '@aws-cdk/cloudformation-include';
import * as tmp from 'tmp';
import CdkDeployAbstraction from "./cdk/cdkDeployAbstraction";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import {ReusableRootStackWithNestedStacks} from './cdk/ReusableRootStackWithNestedStacks';
import {OtherStack} from "./cdk/OtherStack";
import {App} from "@aws-cdk/core";

dotenv.config()

AWS.config.region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
AWS.config.credentials = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
};

const getNestedsStacks = async (stackName: string) => {
    const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
    const resourcesResult = await cloudformation.describeStackResources({
        StackName: stackName
    }).promise();

    const resources = resourcesResult.StackResources;
    const filteredResources = resources.filter(value => value.ResourceType === 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack');

    let nestedStacks: { logicalResourceId: string, physicalResourceId: string; stack: AWS.CloudFormation.Stack }[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filteredResources.length; i++) {
        const resource = filteredResources[i];

        const nestedStackResult = await cloudformation.describeStacks({
            StackName: resource.PhysicalResourceId
        }).promise();

        nestedStacks.push({
            logicalResourceId: resource.LogicalResourceId,
            physicalResourceId: resource.PhysicalResourceId,
            stack: nestedStackResult.Stacks.shift()
        });
    }

    return nestedStacks;
}

const getNestedsStackDetails = async (stackName: string) => {
    const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
    const currentNestedStacks = await getNestedsStacks(stackName);

    let nestedStacks: { [stackName: string]: cfninc.CfnIncludeProps; } = undefined;
    for (let i = 0; i < currentNestedStacks.length; i++) {
        const currentNestedStack = currentNestedStacks[i];

        const nestedStackResult = await cloudformation.describeStacks({
            StackName: currentNestedStack.stack.StackName
        }).promise();

        const nestedStack = nestedStackResult.Stacks.shift();
        const nestedStackTemplate = await cloudformation.getTemplate({
            StackName: nestedStack.StackName
        }).promise();

        const tmpFileName = tmp.tmpNameSync({
            postfix: '.yaml'
        });

        fs.writeFileSync(tmpFileName, nestedStackTemplate.TemplateBody);

        if (!nestedStacks) {
            nestedStacks = {};
        }
        const recursiveNestedStacks = await getNestedsStackDetails(nestedStack.StackName);
        nestedStacks[currentNestedStack.logicalResourceId] = {
            templateFile: tmpFileName,
            parameters: nestedStack.Parameters.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
                previousValue[currentValue.ParameterKey] = currentValue.ParameterValue;
                return previousValue;
            }, {}),
            loadNestedStacks: recursiveNestedStacks
        }
    }

    return nestedStacks;
}

const getStackDetails = async (stackName: string) => {
    const cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();
    const stacksResult = await cloudformation.describeStacks({
        StackName: stackName,
    }).promise();

    const stack = stacksResult.Stacks.shift();
    const stackTemplate = await cloudformation.getTemplate({
        StackName: stack.StackName,
    }).promise();

    const tmpFileName = tmp.tmpNameSync({
        postfix: '.yaml'
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(tmpFileName, stackTemplate.TemplateBody);

    const nestedsStacksDetails = await getNestedsStackDetails(stack.StackName)

    return {
        mainStack: {
            stack,
            tmpFileName
        },
        nestedsStacksDetails
    }
}

const main = async (rootStackName: string) => {
    const stackName = rootStackName;
    const stackDetails = await getStackDetails(stackName);

    const app = new App();
    const rootStack = new ReusableRootStackWithNestedStacks(app,
        stackName,
        stackDetails.mainStack.tmpFileName,
        stackDetails.nestedsStacksDetails,
        stackDetails.mainStack.stack
    );
    new OtherStack(rootStack, 'OtherStack')

    const deploy = new CdkDeployAbstraction({
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION
    });

    const deployResult = await deploy.deployCdkStack(app, rootStack);
    console.log(deployResult);
}

main('MyAwesomeRootStackName')
    .then(value => console.log('finish!'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

**src/cdk/ReusableRootStackWithNestedStacks.ts**

```typescript
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import {Construct, Stack, StackProps} from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as cfninc from '@aws-cdk/cloudformation-include';

export class ReusableRootStackWithNestedStacks extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, tmpFileName: string, nestedStacks: { [stackName: string]: cfninc.CfnIncludeProps; }, stack: AWS.CloudFormation.Stack, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const template = new cfninc.CfnInclude(this, 'CfCurrentTemplate', {
            templateFile: tmpFileName,
            loadNestedStacks: nestedStacks,
            parameters: stack.Parameters.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
                previousValue[currentValue.ParameterKey] = currentValue.ParameterValue;
                return previousValue;
            }, {})
        });
    }
}
```

**src/cdk/OtherStack.ts:**

```typescript
import {Construct, NestedStack, NestedStackProps} from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';

export class OtherStack extends NestedStack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: NestedStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new iam.ManagedPolicy(this, 'IamManagedPolicy', {
            managedPolicyName: 'TesteIAM-ManagedPolicy',
            document: new iam.PolicyDocument({
                statements: [
                    new iam.PolicyStatement({
                        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                        actions: [
                            'dynamodb:GetItem',
                            'dynamodb:Query',
                        ],
                        resources: ['*']
                    })
                ]
            }),
        })
    }
}
```

**src/cdk/cdkDeployAbstraction:**

```typescript
import {Credentials} from "@aws-sdk/types";
import {CloudFormationDeployments} from "aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments";
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import {App, Stack} from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {CloudFormationStackArtifact} from '@aws-cdk/cx-api';
import {DeployStackResult, SdkProvider} from "aws-cdk/lib";

export default class CdkDeployAbstraction {
    private readonly credentials: Credentials;
    private readonly region: string;

    constructor(config: { credentials?: Credentials; region: string }) {
        this.credentials = config.credentials;
        this.region = config.region;
    }

    public async deployCdkStack(app: App, stack: Stack, notificationTopicArn?: string): Promise<DeployStackResult> {
        const stackArtifact = app.synth().getStackByName(stack.stackName) as unknown as CloudFormationStackArtifact;
        const credentialProviderChain = new AWS.CredentialProviderChain();

        let credentials;
        if (this.credentials) {
            credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
                accessKeyId: this.credentials.accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: this.credentials.secretAccessKey,
            });

            credentialProviderChain.providers.push(credentials);
        }

        const sdkProvider = new SdkProvider(credentialProviderChain, this.region, {
            credentials: credentials,
        });

        const cloudFormation = new CloudFormationDeployments({sdkProvider});
        if (notificationTopicArn) {
            return cloudFormation.deployStack({
                // @ts-ignore
                stack: stackArtifact,
                notificationArns: [notificationTopicArn],
                quiet: true,
            });
        }
        return cloudFormation.deployStack({
            // @ts-ignore
            stack: stackArtifact,
            quiet: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into the creation of custom Constructs. If you are going to be reusing the same formats but with different parameters, then this is entirely what custom constructs was designed for.

You can even then package them and put them available for install, to be used by your clients directly if need be.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is:

#### 1. Create root stack

Create a core root stack containing the common resources you want the customer stacks to use. You will need the arn/name of the resources you want to have access to in your customer stacks. One way is to use `CfnOutput` to write to the `cdk.context.json` file:

```
  // Example of outputting an S3 bucket
 const myBucket = new Bucket...
 new CfnOutput(this, "MyBucketARN", {
      value: String(myBucket.bucketARn)
    })
```

#### 2. Create customer root stack

For each customer you would have something such as a customerRootStack which defines the root resources that you already created - since you don't want to overwrite/recreate you will want to create them using the existing ARN/name for example:

```
// Read the root stack context 
import rootData from '../commonApp/cdk.context.json`

s3.Bucket.fromBucketArn(this, 'MyBucket', rootData.nameOfRootStack.MyBucketARN)

// Define custom stuff for each customer
...
```

Note that it is possible to have multiple apps in same folder but you will need to ensure unique names etc) - probably easier to have a project per customer and one for root but that's up to you.

Comment: There’s happen in different moments and it’s not required to have the second nested stack. It will be defined according with the use of our software, on-the-fly). Maybe zero or tens of new stacks. My requirement maybe que be translated to: how setup a parent existing stack on a Nested Stack?

Comment: Ok - maybe I understand - revised answer. I didn't use any nested stacks so to speak (thats more for organization) - what I have is a root stack and a stack for each customer that declares existing resources.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I do not have the cdk.context.json in my project, the deploy is executed in a Lambda function programatically. I think that using something like cloudformation._fromCloudformation is the way but I can't understand how to use that

Comment: Ah I see. Well ARNs are only one option - you can reference things by name for example in which case you can hardcode all of these lookup references.

Comment: Found a way to work here.. posting soon